# Select Multiple without ctrl key in Blazor

Tags: blazor

I have this page:

```
<select multiple>
    @foreach (var item in myVar)
    {
        <option value="@item.SlctValue" 
                selected="@(item.Selected)" 
                @onclick:stopPropagation="true" @onclick:preventDefault="true" 
                @onclick=@((e) => OptionClickEvent(@item, e))>
            @item.SlctName
        </option>
    }
</select>

@foreach (var holderItem in myHolder)
{
    @holderItem
}


@code {
    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);

        //jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("interop.selectMultipleOnclick");
    }

    //Dictionary<int, ElementReference> options = new Dictionary<int, ElementReference>();

    private List<int> myHolder = new List<int>();

    private List<SelectModel> myVar = new List<SelectModel>()
   {
      new SelectModel(){ SlctValue = 1, SlctName="One Year" },
      new SelectModel(){ SlctValue = 2, SlctName="Two Year" },
      new SelectModel(){ SlctValue = 3, SlctName="Three Year" },
      new SelectModel(){ SlctValue = 4, SlctName="Four Year" },
   };

    public void OptionClickEvent(SelectModel item, MouseEventArgs evnt)
    {
        if (myHolder.Contains(item.SlctValue))
        {
            myHolder.Remove(item.SlctValue);
            item.Selected = false;
            return;
        }
        myHolder.Add(item.SlctValue);
        item.Selected = true;
    }

    public class SelectModel
    {
        public string SlctName { get; set; }
        public int SlctValue { get; set; }
        public bool Selected { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But this code does not select multiple items without ctrl key.
I instead tried to use javascript through interop but it acts weired and not working correctly. and this is the javascript I used in second way (that I call from onafterrender js interop):

```
selectMultipleOnclick: function () {
    $('select[multiple] option').on('mouseup', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //var originalScrollTop = $(this).parent().scrollTop();
        //console.log(originalScrollTop);
        $(this).prop('selected', $(this).prop('selected') ? false : true);
        //var self = this;
        $(this).parent().focus();
        //setTimeout(function () {
        //    $(self).parent().scrollTop(originalScrollTop);
        //}, 0);

        return false;
    });
}
```

How to correct these if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add this script at the end of the `index.html` file :

```js
<script>
    window.multiSelectClickedHandler = (elemSelector, dotNetObjRef ) => {
 
        var options = document.querySelectorAll(`${elemSelector} option`);
  
        options.forEach(function (element) {
            element.addEventListener("mousedown", 
                function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    element.parentElement.focus();
                    this.selected = !this.selected;

                    dotNetObjRef.invokeMethodAsync("OptionClickEvent",+e.target.value);
                    return false;

                }, false );
        });
    }
    
</script>
```

And then change the component codes as below :

```cs
@page "/" 
@using System.Linq
@using System.Text.Json
@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime


<select multiple id="mySelect">
@foreach (var item in myVar)
{
   <option value="@item.SlctValue" selected="@item.Selected">
        @item.SlctName
   </option>
 }
</select>


@foreach (var holderItem in myVar.Where(x => x.Selected))
{
  @holderItem.SlctValue
}

@code {

    private List<SelectModel> myVar = new List<SelectModel>()
    {
        new SelectModel(){ SlctValue = 1, SlctName="One Year",Selected = true},
        new SelectModel(){ SlctValue = 2, SlctName="Two Year",Selected = true },
        new SelectModel(){ SlctValue = 3, SlctName="Three Year" ,Selected = true},
        new SelectModel(){ SlctValue = 4, SlctName="Four Year" },
    };

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            var dotNetObjRef = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
            await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("multiSelectClickedHandler", "#mySelect", dotNetObjRef);
        }

        await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
    }


    [JSInvokable]
    public void OptionClickEvent(JsonElement value)
    {
        var selectedValue = value.GetInt32();

        var selectItem = myVar.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SlctValue == selectedValue);

        if (selectItem is null) return;

        selectItem.Selected = !selectItem.Selected;

        StateHasChanged();
    }

    public class SelectModel
    {
        public string SlctName { get; set; }
        public int SlctValue { get; set; }
        public bool Selected { get; set; }
    }
}
```